# Optimal hosting of website and platform api on EC2

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, memory, jboss, architecture

We intend to deploy a web site (based on Drupal) and the associated platform api on Amazon EC2. Would like to know what would be a better way to architect this solution w.r.t to instances (meaning shall we deploy these on separate instances or can keep it on the same instance without hampering performance?). Also, if we host apache and jboss side-by-side on the same instance, would it hamper performance (w.r.t Heap and memory) or hosting both the website and associated platform api on Jboss would be efficient? Would appreciate any pros and cons for these.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should try first on one instance and monitor performance, I/O wait, etc.. Then you would know for sure. It depends mostly on number of requests rather then on what you described